# probability of drawing a matched pair in two draws from group of many different pairs

Tags: probability

Given a group of $20$ people with blood types: $A = 6, B = 2, AB = 3, O = 9$. What is the probability that two people chosen at random will have the same blood type? I determined that there are $55$ possible pairs $[A: C(6,2)=15, B: C(2,2)=1, AB: C(3,2)= 3, O: C(9,2)=36]$, and I can figure out the probability of each blood type pair individually, but adding them gives too large a number.

Comment: I'd go case by case, $AA$ for instance:  first one $A$ has probability $\frac 6{20}$.  Second one then has probability $\frac 5{19}$, so $P(AA)=\frac 6{20}\times \frac 5{19}$.  And so on.

Comment: Can you count the number of ways that two people can be chosen from the group of 20?  Then divide 55 by this number to arrive at your probability

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have correctly calculated that there are $55$ possible choices that will produce a pair of donors with matching blood type.  The total number of ways to choose two donors is $C(20,2) = 190$.  So, the probability of randomly drawing two people with the same blood type is $\frac{55}{190}$.

Comment: The OP correctly calculated that there are $55$ possible selections that will produce a pair of donors with matching blood types.  There is no need to hedge.

Comment: @Taussig doesn't the OP asks for a probability, not the total number of possible selections?

Comment: Yes.  Your answer is correct.  I am just suggesting that you explicitly state that the OP has calculated the numerator correctly.

Comment: OK I see now.  Edited the answer to reflect this.